# How regex quotes python

Tags: python

I have a string like `"[{"title": "something with {"}", "pub_year": 1988}, {"title": "something with {"}", "pub_year": 1988}...]"`.

I want to convert this to `"[{"title": "something without {"}", "pub_year": 1988}, {"title": "something without {"}", "pub_year": 1988}...]"`

I think I should use replace but I don't quite understand how.

Comment: That's not a valid string. Maybe this is the *contents* of the string, and it's actually contained in single quotes? Please [edit] to clarify. For reference, see [mre]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: Is this supposed to be JSON data? Cause it's close, but again the double-quotes inside double-quotes is not valid. Also the ellipsis.

Comment: When you say "replace", you mean `str.replace`, right? Why are you talking about regex too? It doesn't look like you need to use regex for this.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) some code that uses `mystring.replace('{"}', 'some new value')`. Consider using [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to get at the individual key,value strings.

Comment: @J_H `json.loads`? It's not valid JSON, as I commented above.

Comment: @J_H `.replace('{"}'`? That's not what they want to replace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need re to do this but just in case you do then:

```
import re

a = """[{"title": "something with {"}", "pub_year": 1988}, {"title": "something with {"}", "pub_year": 1988}...]"""

b = re.sub(r'\bwith\b', 'without', a)

print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[{"title": "something without {"}", "pub_year": 1988}, {"title": "something without {"}", "pub_year": 1988}...]
```

Quite what you're going to do with the resultant string is a mystery